# Reading large data files quickly in Java

Tags: java, file

I have a large .txt file with data in lines in the format

> String int int double int int int double

eg:

> monday 1 -1 43.5 2 1 1 -99999
>
> tuesday 3 12 43.02 4 11 12 5.2

My text file has approximately 20,000 lines so i need a quick method of reading this in java.

What is the quickest method to read this kind of file in?

---

EDIT: I have used a function named textscan in MATLAB which worked perfectly (however i want to use java) so a similarly fast method would be perfect

Comment: Use .split(" ") method.

Comment: 20000 lines? That's not a lot. Any reasonable technique for reading a file should work and be efficient enough for most purposes. [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) is probably the most convenient.

Comment: You should be able to read about a million lines per second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String scan;
        FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\workspace\\learn\\scan.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);

        while((scan = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
            System.out.println(scan);
                }
        br.close();
```